# How to convert a variable to be used in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have stored Job_id value of msdb..sysjob in a variable @job_id_char, which i want to use against msdb..sysjobactivity to get the 'start_execution_date' value.
I have used following query but getting error as conversion failed

```
select start_execution_date from msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity where job_id = @job_id_char
```

I know that i have to convert the variable, but i don't know how

Comment: Could you check the 'Job_id' and 'run_status' of respective 'Job_id column' of 'msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity' in 'msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory' . In 'msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory'  the  'run_status' is '1' or not.

Answer (score 2):

Since the data type of the `job_id` in the `msdb.dbo.sysjob` table is [`uniqueidentifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189817.aspx).

So you need to create the `@job_id_char` as a `uniqueidentifier` variable, like
`DECLARE @job_id_char uniqueidentifier`
then only it can be used in the `WHERE` clause of `msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity` table.

Or you can JOIN the tables by the the `job_id` like

```
SELECT sja.start_execution_date, .....
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sja ON sj.job_id = sja.job_id
WHERE ..... -- condition related sysjobs tables
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the data type of the job_id column, and make sure your variable's data type matches exactly.